# 500 - Internal server error with "resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Tags: iis-7, crm, sage-crm

I have created a entry page and created fields for all those. Now am trying to entered fields into my database.

My values are save in database but after saving my CRM page shows error like

> 500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I think this error may be because of not enabling parent path and authentication rights in IIS.

I enabled the allow parent path in IIs->ASP,iis->Asp->debugging properties->send errors to browser->true

How to resolve  this error?

Answer (score 14):

I figured out that in IIS7.

I had to go to the site in question, to 'Error Pages' --> "Edit Feature Settings" and select "Detailed errors". It's a little dialog box that pops up with three radio buttons.

This fixed it for me. Simply setting "Send Errors To Browser" to true, did not do the trick.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: it saved my day

Comment: Where this option "Send Errors To Browser" show up? When I select "Detailed errors", I can't see the "Send Errors To Browser" option. I'm using IIS7.